# Vue.js 3 runtime component compiler

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to create a fully customized Vue.js application and what I want is to save Vue.js component in database and load the corresponding Vue.js component based on the user.

That will make the app fully customized and I can customize component for each user individually.

Is there any library can compile Vue.js 3 component (composition API) on the fly?